# keeping contents and its size when resizing browser window bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

These question may be simple to you guys. But as a beginner this is quite interesting to me. I am creating a responsive website with bootstrap. Everything is fine till i found out something different in my website i built. Here is what i built with my lil knowledge about bootstrap - [my website](http://kitchenscaape.comxa.com/).  But when i compared it with other website like [this](http://www.indtextile.com/). You can see the difference when you resize the browser window. In the latter one. Only the side extra space is reducing when the browser is resized and the main content elements and its size stays the same. But here in [my website](http://kitchenscaape.comxa.com/) the content moves and changes position when resized. I have compared other bootstrap websites like [this one](http://pages.revox.io/dashboard/). As you can in the links. My website behaves differently. I don't understand why it is happening with my site. Am i doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `container` or `container-fluid` to create a responsive container which you are not using.

From bootstrap [website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/),

> Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.

and

> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

Comment: so i want to wrap all my contents into container div right ?

Comment: yeah. wrap them in `container` div. Look at their [website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for examples.